# From what horror film is this clip of a grey-skinned, clawed hand emerging from a tree root?

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, folklore

There are a lot of film clips used in the folk horror documentary, *Woodlands Dark And Days Bewitched: A History Of Folk Horror*, and as far as I can tell, not all them are identified for the viewer.

Toward the end of the documentary, a few minutes into the sixth and final segment, "Folk Horror Revival," there were two such unidentified clips back-to-back that caught my eye.

I took photos of both from the TV screen. This one shows a grey-skinned, clawed hand emerging from a tree root:

[image: Screenshot of grey-skinned, clawed hand emerging from a tree root]

Does anyone know what film this clip is taken from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That image is from ***[The Wretched](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8305806/)*** (2019).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wretched_(film)):

> *The Wretched* is a 2019 American supernatural horror film written and directed by the Pierce Brothers. It stars John-Paul Howard, Piper Curda, Zarah Mahler, Kevin Bigley, Gabriela Quezada Bloomgarden, Richard Ellis, Blane Crockarell, Jamison Jones, and Azie Tesfai. The film follows a defiant teenage boy who faces off with an evil witch posing as the neighbor next door.

The shot in question is visible at around the 1:00 mark in the video below.

Comment: That looks interesting, but 3 Hours+ might be a little much!